# if db connection true load migrations codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a form where I can fill out my database details, and then it gets placed in the database.php file.

**Problem**

When I click on the submit button it should load my migrations but can not load migrations because saying incorrect database name.

The reason Is because it loads at same time as the database and does not pick the name up yet.

Is there away to run the loadMigrations function once established db connection or database name.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('hostname', 'Hostname', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Database Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('database', 'Database', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('driver', 'Database Driver');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('prefix', 'Database Prefix'); 

$this->load->library('form_validation');

if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == false) {

$this->load->view('template/step_3');

} else {    

$data = array();
$data['hostname']   = $this->input->post('hostname');
$data['username']   = $this->input->post('username');
$data['password']   = $this->input->post('password');
$data['database']   = $this->input->post('database');
$data['driver'] = $this->input->post('driver');
$data['prefix']  = $this->input->post('prefix');

$data  = $this->load->view('template/configuration/database', $data, true);
write_file(dirname(FCPATH) . '/admin/application/config/database.php', $data, 'r+');
write_file(dirname(FCPATH) . '/catalog/config/database.php', $data, 'r+');
write_file(FCPATH . '/application/config/database.php', $data, 'r+');

/* 
|
|   This migration does not work because will not pick up database name
|   You all ways have to refresh page. Need away that can load migrations
|   Once there is a database name in the database.php file.
|
*/

$this->load->dbutil();
if($this->dbutil->database_exists($this->input->post('database'))) {
$this->load->library('migration');
$this->migration->version(1);
redirect('step_4'); // connected, go on
} else {
redirect('step_3'); // failed, go back
}   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check db connection like following:

```
$db = $this->load->database('default', true);

if($connected = $db->initialize()) 
{
     redirect('step_4'); // connected, go on
} 
else
{
     redirect('step_3'); // failed, go back
}
```

**Another Way**

```
// Returns boolean or mysql/mysqli object
function test_db_connection()
{
    $hostname = $this->input->post('hostname');
    $database = $this->input->post('database');
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $driver   = $this->input->post('driver');

    if($driver == 'mysqli')
    {
        return function_exists('mysqli_connect') && @mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
    }

    $link = @mysql_connect("$hostname", $username, $password);
    return $link && mysql_select_db("$database", $link)
}
```

This function that i'm using is working right. If doesnt work, check your codes again.

Comment: where would you recommend to try that because I tried it earlier in the form validation area and did not work.

Comment: tried your first way and worked OK. Second way was way I had tried it before.

Comment: I tried it again with code above today and now does not work will not run my sql because has not picked up database name.

Comment: I don't use mysql connect because I set dbdriver in the form what I choose between mysqli and or mysql

Comment: @acoderslife Updated.. Its was only examples.. Dont wait exactly answer that  you expected. You can get inspiration from answers...